# Setting class member with callback in thread-safe way

Tags: c++, multithreading, callback, c++14

I have the following class that allows setting a value via an expensive computation, and we can pretend that computation takes place asynchronously in some other thread.  The class also has a method to get the current value, perhaps doing that computation synchronously if needed:

```
class Example {
  public:
    Example() : x_(0) {}
    void Set(int x) {
        SomeOtherFunc(x, callback_, false);
    }

    void Finished(int y) {
      x_ = y;
    }

    const int Get() {
      if (!x_) {
          SomeOtherFunc(1, callback_, true);
      }
      return x_;
    }

  private:
    int x_;
    std::function<void(int)> callback_ =
        std::bind(&Example::Finished, this, std::placeholders::_1);
};
```

And let's pretend this function:

```
void SomeOtherFunc(int x, const std::function<void(int)>& func,
                   bool blocking) {
  // Do something expensive, in another thread, possibly blocking.
  func(x * 2);
}
```

This works the way I would like:

```
Example e1, e2;
e1.Set(5);
// "10 2"
std::cout << e1.Get() << " " << e2.Get();
```

My concerns are is the following scenario:

```
Example e;
e.Set(10); // Takes a while
e.Get();   // Need the value now
```

My questions:

1. Is the `Example` class thread-safe? If not, how can it be made so? Seems like locks would work, but could be overkill.
2. Since the work in `SomeOtherFunc` is expensive, I only want to call that function once. Having a flag inside the class that gets set to true whenever a call is made, and is checked before a call is made, seems reasonable (but is it thread-safe?).  The problem is, if I call `Set` and then `Get` immediately afterwards, I want `Get` to return the "final" value for `x_`.  How can I ensure that?  That is, if that flag is set, how do I make `Get` wait for the callback to complete in a thread-safe way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Example` class is not thread-safe because the integer `x_` can be modified concurrently, which may lead to undefined behavior (data race).
In addition, your expensive calculation may be performed multiple times since you have a race condition in `Get()` by checking `x_` and then calling the function that will set it.
You need a mechanism that guarantees that the value for `x_` will be calculated exactly once while fully thread-safe (`Set()` and `Get()` may be called concurrently).

The standard library provides a mechanism to exactly solve that problem, `call_once()`, designed to implement one-shot events while shared data is properly synchronized between threads.
You can use it like this:

```
#include <mutex>

class Example {
  public:
    ...

    void Set(int x) {
        std::call_once(flag, SomeOtherFunc, x, callback_, false);
    }

    ...

    const int Get() {
        std::call_once(flag, SomeOtherFunc, 1, callback_, true);
        return x_;
    }

  private:
    std::once_flag flag;
    ...
};
```

This also handles the scenario whereby `Get()` has to wait while your callback is working on the result.

Note that you no longer can (and have to) check for the value of `x_` in `Get()` because that would constitute a data race (another thread might be updating `x_` at the same time).

Also note that it is not thread safe to call your callback `Finished()` directly. Probably best to move that to the `private:` section.

Comment: So call_once will block in `Get()` if a call is currently under way? That's pretty much exactly what I want.

Comment: @SteveD Yes, that is guaranteed by `call_once`.. All (concurrent) calls to `Get()` (and `Set()`) will block if and while a calculation by `SomeOtherFunc()` is underway, regardless whether initiated by `Get()` or `Set()`

Comment: Thanks again, this is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a [future](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future).

> The class template std::future provides a mechanism to access the result of asynchronous operations:
>   An asynchronous operation (created via std::async, std::packaged_task, or std::promise) can provide a std::future object to the creator of that asynchronous operation.
>   The creator of the asynchronous operation can then use a variety of methods to query, wait for, or extract a value from the std::future. These methods may block if the asynchronous operation has not yet provided a value.
>   When the asynchronous operation is ready to send a result to the creator, it can do so by modifying shared state (e.g. std::promise::set_value) that is linked to the creator's std::future.